# Data Structures within Databases

Tags: database, data-structures

I have an idea for an application, and it requires a graph data structure.  I will have nodes that contain text, numbers, and pointers to other nodes. The edges will have a certain weight and I want to be able to traverse my graph efficiently.  This graph will be HUGE, so naturally I want to use a database.  I understand how to store the text and numbers in a database object, but I don't understand how I can store the pointers to other nodes.

It seems to me that most data structures use this idea of a node connected to other nodes, so there must be an easy way to do it with a database, I just can't find it for the life of me.

How can I have a database entry that has a field that points to another database entry?

How can I create a data structure within a database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! For starters what database are you using? You need to show us more of what you have tried and researched. See the [how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: Maybe you should explore using a graph database like [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/) instead of a relational database?

Comment: @Madness  I actually am just in the beginning stages of my project, still just ironing out the plan so I haven't nailed down any specifics like that, it's just an idea.  I will keep that in mind for my next questions though, thanks! :D

Comment: @jpw Wow! I never know things like that existed! Thank you, I think I will actually use Neo4J, it seems perfect for my project

Comment: There's a lot to be said for going with what you know.  I would consider Neo4J for any project that faced the problem of persisting objects that were not predictable or whose form down the road might not be known.  If your data model is pretty well known at design time and you had confidence in its stability (which is a pretty common scenario), I would probably stay with tried and true RDBMSs.

Comment: @scottb  To be completely honest, I have never done serious work with databases (only with very simple data models), so I will have to work out what my exact needs are.  However, I do think it'll be a constant data model, so I will probably end up going with RDBMs.  I do want to explore my options with other models though (so I can gain knowledge for future projects).  Thanks again for all your advice, I didn't know databases were such a wide field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question gets at the impedance mismatch between relational databases and object-oriented development environments like Java.

- Database tables map relationships between each other using keys; tables have no notion or concept of object-oriented principles like inheritance.
- Memory resident objects have references to map relationships and use composition and inheritance to build hierarchies and graphs of objects.  Hierarchies and composition are not native concepts in relational databases.

A straightforward way to get at your problem is to use an ORM framework to take these impedance mismatch issues out of your problem domain.

- Develop your domain object model as you would for any object-oriented  application (i.e., using composition and inheritance)
- When complete, map your objects with a JPA framework such as Hibernate, which will do the ORM for you
- As long as your domain object model is well-formed and the JPA mapping is correct, then JPA will take care of the problem of mapping your objects into a database and vice-versa.

ORM isn't magic.  It won't take a poorly conceived or suboptimally conceived domain object model and fix its problems in the database layer.  It really does pay off to spend time getting the domain object model right, tight, concise, and efficient before you begin the work of using it with JPA.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a little new to databases, so I have a lot of work to do, but your answer has gotten me on the right track :D.  I up-voted your answer but it said I didn't have enough rep...